# The line between graduate student and undergrad questions

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm trying to find a better home for [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/319700/when-to-give-up-solving-problems-exercises-after-giving-significant-effort/319704#319704).  I'm not sure Academia is a good fit.  This question seems like it could be taken many ways.  But I thought I'd ask before doing anything.  I welcome opinions and ideas.

Comment: The link is no longer valid to the original question, perhaps if you could restate it within this thread. In addition, ask yourself if the original question stated what you have tried, and what did and didn't work about it. The more targeted, focused a question is, the better the responses will be.

Comment: @J.Roibal You can still see it [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:AG_Bet_Vf8UJ:programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/319700/when-to-give-up-solving-problems-exercises-after-giving-significant-effort+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) But I'll probably let the issue die and delete this question.

Comment: How about you might ask the question, "What is the difference in effort required when performing research at an undergraduate level compared to a graduate level?"

Comment: One of the challenges of your original post is that it asked many questions and SE is one question per post which provides a better opportunity for complete answers.

Comment: You are welcome to ask it if you think it will be well received.

Comment: Here is a question with a similar area to yours, with some fantastic answers by experienced programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/150091/how-to-become-a-super-user-programming

Comment: @J.Roibal My post?  @ morbidCode wrote that post.  I was just a friendly mod trying to find it a home before it died.

Comment: My apologies, I thought you had written the original post. I am new to SE and just learning the process.

Comment: @J.Roibal no problem.  I like the helpful attitude.  Lots of ropes to learn here.  I appreciate you being willing to show them to someone. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this question would probably be closed on Academia,SE with the close reason:

> "The answer to this question strongly depends on individual factors such as a certain person’s preferences, a given institution’s regulations, the exact contents of your work or your personal values.

Similar questions, like [How much details one should learn when studying mathematics on his own?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/64078/how-much-details-one-should-learn-when-studying-mathematics-on-his-own) have been closed for that reason.

A [comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/319700/when-to-give-up-solving-problems-exercises-after-giving-significant-effort#comment678559_319700) on the question has already expressed that it is a highly individual matter:

> This depends entirely on the individual, and can only be learned from experience. Sadly there's nothing useful we can tell you beyond that. – [Ixrec](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/161917/ixrec)

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Seems there isn't a good place on the stackexchange network to talk about study skills.  Thanks for you time.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Maybe [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/)? Check with them.

Comment: Seems damn silly to down vote this and not comment.  If you have another opinion, share it.